# Can I return multiple content types per one http request?

Tags: asp.net, server-side

Reporting system has list of available reports on a web page. When user clicks on a report new browser window opens, server starts to prepare report (winword document) and then sends it back after 2-10 seconds.

Code in the handler looks like the following:

```
 context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
   "attachment;filename=report.doc");
 context.Response.BinaryWrite(reportDocument);
```

I want to show "please wait" in this new window. Is it possible to prepare html content immediately  ("please wait") send it back and then continue with time-consuming report preparation not closing connection?

What do you suggest if it's not possible to return multiple content types per one http request?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**One HttpResponse can only have sigle MIME type**. You can pop-up another window which in turn can call the server which will respond with winword report document.

Comment: It look like we can (theoretically): http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/489209-transmit-file-html-response

Answer (score 1):

You could create an html Loading page with a redirect to the binary content.

The redirect could be done using meta redirect

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/" />
```

More info at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

Comment: Cool! But there said that it's deprecated technique. Is it reliable?

Comment: i've been using that way and javascript like:

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
self.location='http://xpto.com';
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It's a pity but meta tag as well as javascript approach pops up a new browser window when download report file (would you like to open in microsoft word? yes/no). Whatever I choose old "please wait" window stays on the screen and I found no ability to determine the moment when document is downloaded to close it

Comment: If you add Response.AddHeader "Content-disposition","attachment;filename=myfile.doc" it will appear a "Save? yes/no". If you add Response.AddHeader "Content-disposition","inline;filename=myfile.doc" it will display the document in the browser (if you have office installed in this case). Do you think this can help you? (this server-side code that I use in asp vbscript)

Comment: open/save dialog still present. But yes, now it opens inside browser.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send 2 types of content per response. What you *can* do is render a "Please wait" page which contains a request (like an iframe) to the binary content.

Comment: It looks like we can: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/489209-transmit-file-html-response

Comment: @Andrew Florko , the link looks like a possibility for Http in general, not sure if it'll work on asp.net, but it looks interesting. If you manage to find a way, I'd love to see an example.

Comment: The problem with iframes -- I can't determine the time report document is loaded into iframe. IFrames pop up a new window for winword and previous one is not closed.